# ¿Cuál es la complejidad de un algoritmo: T(n) =3*T(n÷b) +n²+1?

Tags: algoritmos, matemáticas, recursión, complejidad

¿Me pueden ayudar a saber Cuál es la complejidad de: T(n) =3*T(n/b) +n²+1. Cuando n > 1?.

He estado intentando comprender un poco el método maestro para el cálculo de complejidades algorítmicas recursivas ya que tengo que hacer una presentación escolar resolviendo este problema, pero no he podido resolverlo bien. Si me pueden asesorar, lo valoraría bastante.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el *método maestro* al que te refieres? Podrías argumentar un poco ¿qué es lo que entiendes y qué no? No creo que recibas una respuesta clara si no haces una pregunta un poco más concreta. Además, si alguien con una buena base matemática te responde asumiendo que vas a entenderle tal vez quedes en las mismas o peor. Por otro lado, el símbolo `÷` que usas ¿en qué contexto lo aplicas? ¿Es una división? Ya que, usualmente los lenguajes de programación y en matemáticas también, se usa `/` para el operador de división. Saludos

Comment: Totalmente cierto. El método maestro que menciono es para el cálculo de complejidad de algoritmos. Muy utilizado en algoritmos de recursividad. Y en cuanto al símbolo sí es división (/). Muchas gracias

Comment: Se que te refieres al ***Teorema maestro***, que no es un método. ¿Y en qué parte tienes la duda?

Answer (score 1):

*Te lo respondere en texto tipo codigo python que no soy tan habil en la notacion matematica de stack y pierdo mucho tiempo.*

---

### Para resolver ese tipo de problemas se usa el teorema maestro para relaciones recursivas.

en la aplicación de análisis de algoritmos recursivos, las constantes y funciones toman los siguientes significados:

- n es el tamaño del problema a resolver. a es el número de subproblemas en la recursión.
- n/b el tamaño de cada subproblema. (Aquí se asume que todos los subproblemas tienen el mismo tamaño)
- f(n) es el costo del trabajo hecho fuera de las llamadas recursivas, que incluye el costo de la división del problema y el costo de unir las soluciones de los subproblemas.

para este teorema tenemos 3 casos:

Se realiza la notación Big O ( O* )en los siguientes tres casos:

Caso 1:

```
Si F(n) = O*(N**c) donde logb,a. 
usando Cota superior asintótica tenemos:
T(n) = Theta ( n ** log b,a )
```

Caso 2:

```
Si es verdad que para alguna constante k ≥ 0, que:
   
F(n) = Theta (n**c * log(n)**k, donde c=logb,a
   
Entonces F(n) = Theta ( n**C * (log (n))**k+1
```

Caso 3:

```
F(n) = omega ( n**c ) donde c > log b,a

Y si es verdad además que:

alpha * f (n/b)<=kf(n) 
para una n suficientemente 
grande y para alguna constante k<1
```

Y aqui comenzamos con la respuesta.
Para responder esta pregunta primero se detalla lo que tenemos:

```
Si F(n) = 0
T(n) = 3*t(n/6)+n**2
```

okey aqui tenemos

```
a=3,b=6, F(n) = n**2
f(n) = omega( n**c )donde, c=2
```

verificamos que se cumpla la condicion del caso 3:

```
log b,a = log6,3 = 0.61, se cumple
que c > log b,a. 2 > 0.61.
```

La condición también se cumple:

```
3*( n**2 / 6) <= kn**2, eligiendo k=0.5
```

Entonces por el 3er caso tenemos:

```
T(n)=omega(F(n)) = omega (n**2)

Por consiguiente la relación de recurrencia 
T(n) es Θ(n**2).
```